# Wordpress Jetpack Error

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

My site is http://alloccasionsrochester.com/ after attempting to update Jetpack, the error below returned.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on
>   line 31
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on
>   line 31

I figured I could just rename the Jetpack folder in FTP to Jetpack.old but that didn't allow me back into the dashboard. Then I tried to just disable all plugins by renaming the plugins folder to plugins.hold (like the FAQ says to when troubleshooting) and it still had the same Jetpack.php error.

I un-installed Jetpack. Got the same warning:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on
>   line 31
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/pattieb2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on
>   line 31

I re-installed Jetpack. Got

the same warning.

Comment: Best not to reference the output of a URL as "this" as neither the URL or the output may be stable with time. Please include the relevant content in the question.

Comment: @ToddB Removed link to other forum.